# How does class gets stored in window object?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Below code,

```
function myFunc(theObject) {
   theObject.brand = "Toyota";
 }
```

adds a member with property name `myFunc` in `window` object.

```
>  window['myFunc']
     function myFunc()
```

---

For below code,

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

How does `Polygon` get stored in `window` object?

Comment: It does get stored not at all. `class` declarations work like `let`, see the duplicate

Comment: @Bergi—"*It does get stored not at all*". Sorry, can't understand that… ;-)

Comment: You were asking *how* `Polygon` would be stored in `window`. I'm telling you that it doesn't get stored as a property of the global object - it's not a `var` or `function` declaration (and not an undeclared assignment either)